# React not re-rendering when redux store changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I was unable to find the right answer sifting through the others. The issue seems to be that {loopToDo} does not directly reference a prop from the store. How can I set my code up so that it updates when the store changes, like I want it to?

```
@connect((germzFirstStore) => {
    return {
        taskList: germzFirstStore.tasks
    }
})

class TaskBoard extends React.Component {

render() {

    function toDoStatus(value) {
        return value.taskstatus === "toDo";
    }

    var toDoTasks = this.props.taskList.tasks.filter(toDoStatus);
    var loopToDo = toDoTasks.map((tasksEntered) => {
        return (
            <div id={tasksEntered.idtasks} className="taskBox">{tasksEntered.task}</div>
        );
    });

    return(
        <div ref="toDo" id="toDo" className="container toDo">{loopToDo}</div>
    )

    }
}
```

the reducer:

```
const tasksReducer = (state=tasksInitialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === "ADD") {
        state = {...state, tasks: [...state.tasks, action.newTask]}
    }
    return state; }
```

Comment: Just a though even though I doubt it does anything. do: return {...state, } // etc instead of state = {...state, } //etc

Comment: yeah, same result. it's so strange because i had this working earlier with code that functionally looks exactly the same to me

Comment: Could you perhaps modify [this](http://jsfiddle.net/guillaumemaka/jwm6k66c/) fiddle and reproduce your problem? It would take a bit of investigation to figure out this problem

Comment: Also where and how will the data in the store change? add that code too

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that by doing this

```
state = {...state, tasks: [...state.tasks, action.newTask]}
```

You are effectively mutating the state before returning it and that probably is the reason why your components are not re-rendering on updating state.
 What you can do in your reducer is

```
if (action.type === "ADD") {
    return {...state, tasks: [...state.tasks, action.newTask]}
}
```

or

```
if (action.type === "ADD") {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {tasks: [...state.tasks, action.newTask]})
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If germzFirstStore.tasks has updated then the component will re-render it has nothing to do with what is inside the render function. My guess is that you are mutating the state in your reducer instead of updating it and returning the updated version of the state.

Comment: reducer added to the post